# Installing "gnome-control-center" after Upgrade to 20 yields "pkgProblemResolver" error

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies, gnome-control-center

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20 from 18 and the settings where missing. I tried to install them with:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Which fails with:

> E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Debugging with `sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install gnome-control-center` results into:

> Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2 Starting 2
> pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2 Investigating (0)
> libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 < 21.1.0~kisak1~b @ii mK Ib > Broken
> libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 Depends on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mR
>
> > (>= 1:3.0.0)   Considering libsensors4:amd64 -1 as a solution to libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 40   Added libsensors4:amd64 to the remove list
> > Fixing libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 via keep of libsensors4:amd64
> > Investigating (0) libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 < 21.1.0~kisak1~b @ii mK Ib >
> > Broken libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 Depends on libsensors4:i386 < 1:3.4.0-4
> > @ii mR > (>= 1:3.0.0)   Considering libsensors4:i386 -1 as a solution
> > to libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 1   Added libsensors4:i386 to the remove list
> > Fixing libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 via keep of libsensors4:i386 Investigating
> > (0) libsensors-config:amd64 < none -> 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @rc uN Ib >
> > Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:amd64 <
> > 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >   Considering libsensors4:amd64 -1 as a solution to
> > libsensors-config:amd64 0   Added libsensors4:amd64 to the remove list
> > Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:i386 <
> > 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >   Considering libsensors4:i386 -1 as a solution to
> > libsensors-config:amd64 0   Added libsensors4:i386 to the remove list
> > Fixing libsensors-config:amd64 via remove of libsensors4:amd64
> > Fixing libsensors-config:amd64 via remove of libsensors4:i386
> > Investigating (1) libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 < 21.1.0~kisak1~b @ii mK Ib >
> > Broken libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 Depends on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4
> > @ii mR > (>= 1:3.0.0)   Considering libsensors4:amd64 -1 as a solution
> > to libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 40   Added libsensors4:amd64 to the remove
> > list   Fixing libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 via keep of libsensors4:amd64
> > Investigating (1) libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 < 21.1.0~kisak1~b @ii mK Ib >
> > Broken libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 Depends on libsensors4:i386 < 1:3.4.0-4
> > @ii mR > (>= 1:3.0.0)   Considering libsensors4:i386 -1 as a solution
> > to libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 1   Added libsensors4:i386 to the remove list
> > Fixing libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 via keep of libsensors4:i386 Investigating
> > (1) libsensors-config:amd64 < none -> 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @rc uN Ib >
> > Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:amd64 <
> > 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >   Considering libsensors4:amd64 -1 as a solution to
> > libsensors-config:amd64 0   Added libsensors4:amd64 to the remove list
> > Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:i386 <
> > 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >   Considering libsensors4:i386 -1 as a solution to
> > libsensors-config:amd64 0   Added libsensors4:i386 to the remove list
> > Fixing libsensors-config:amd64 via remove of libsensors4:amd64
> > Fixing libsensors-config:amd64 via remove of libsensors4:i386
> > Investigating (2) libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 < 21.1.0~kisak1~b @ii mK Ib >
> > Broken libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 Depends on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4
> > @ii mR > (>= 1:3.0.0)   Considering libsensors4:amd64 -1 as a solution
> > to libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 40   Added libsensors4:amd64 to the remove
> > list   Fixing libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 via keep of libsensors4:amd64
> > Investigating (2) libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 < 21.1.0~kisak1~b @ii mK Ib >
> > Broken libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 Depends on libsensors4:i386 < 1:3.4.0-4
> > @ii mR > (>= 1:3.0.0)   Considering libsensors4:i386 -1 as a solution
> > to libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 1   Added libsensors4:i386 to the remove list
> > Fixing libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 via keep of libsensors4:i386 Investigating
> > (2) libsensors-config:amd64 < none -> 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @rc uN Ib >
> > Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:amd64 <
> > 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >   Considering libsensors4:amd64 40 as a solution to
> > libsensors-config:amd64 0   Holding Back libsensors-config:amd64
> > rather than change libsensors4:amd64 Investigating (3)
> > libsensors5:amd64 < none -> 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uN Ib > Broken
> > libsensors5:amd64 Depends on libsensors-config:amd64 < none |
> > 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @rc uH >   Considering libsensors-config:amd64 0 as a
> > solution to libsensors5:amd64 0   Holding Back libsensors5:amd64
> > rather than change libsensors-config:amd64 Investigating (4)
> > libsnmp35:amd64 < none -> 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3 @un uN Ib > Broken
> > libsnmp35:amd64 Depends on libsensors5:amd64 < none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1
> > @un uH > (>= 1:3.5.0)   Considering libsensors5:amd64 0 as a solution
> > to libsnmp35:amd64 2   Holding Back libsnmp35:amd64 rather than change
> > libsensors5:amd64 Investigating (5) libsane:amd64 < none ->
> > 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uN Ib > Broken libsane:amd64 Depends on libsnmp35:amd64 < none | 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3 @un uH > (>= 5.8+dfsg)
> > Considering libsnmp35:amd64 2 as a solution to libsane:amd64 7
> > Holding Back libsane:amd64 rather than change libsnmp35:amd64
> > Investigating (5) sane-utils:amd64 < none -> 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uN
> > Ib > Broken sane-utils:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64 < none |
> > 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uH > (>= 1.0.27)   Considering libsane:amd64 7 as a solution to sane-utils:amd64 2   Holding Back sane-utils:amd64
> > rather than change libsane:amd64 Investigating (6) colord:amd64 < none
> > -> 1.4.4-2 @rc uN Ib > Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64 < none | 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uH > (>= 1.0.24)   Considering
> > libsane:amd64 7 as a solution to colord:amd64 32   Holding Back
> > colord:amd64 rather than change libsane:amd64 Investigating (7)
> > gnome-control-center:amd64 < none -> 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu2 @un puN Ib >
> > Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on colord:amd64 < none |
> > 1.4.4-2 @rc uH > (>= 0.1.30)   Considering colord:amd64 32 as a solution to gnome-control-center:amd64 10035   Re-Instated
> > libsensors-config:amd64   Re-Instated libsensors5:amd64   Re-Instated
> > libsnmp35:amd64   Re-Instated libsane:amd64   Re-Instated colord:amd64
> > Investigating (7) libsensors-config:amd64 < none -> 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1
> > @rc uN Ib > Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on
> > libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >   Considering libsensors4:amd64
> > 40 as a solution to libsensors-config:amd64 0   Holding Back
> > libsensors-config:amd64 rather than change libsensors4:amd64
> > Investigating (8) libsensors5:amd64 < none -> 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uN
> > Ib > Broken libsensors5:amd64 Depends on libsensors-config:amd64 <
> > none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @rc uH >   Considering libsensors-config:amd64
> > 0 as a solution to libsensors5:amd64 0   Holding Back
> > libsensors5:amd64 rather than change libsensors-config:amd64
> > Investigating (9) libsnmp35:amd64 < none -> 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3 @un uN
> > Ib > Broken libsnmp35:amd64 Depends on libsensors5:amd64 < none |
> > 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uH > (>= 1:3.5.0)   Considering libsensors5:amd64
> > 0 as a solution to libsnmp35:amd64 2   Holding Back libsnmp35:amd64
> > rather than change libsensors5:amd64 Done Some packages could not be
> > installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible
> > situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
> > required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of
> > Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libsane : Depends:
> libsnmp35 (>= 5.8+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
> Recommends: sane-utils (>= 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2) E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by
> held packages.

How do I need to proceed from here?

Comment: Looks to me like your upgrade from "18" to "20" was unsuccessful. The simplest solution is to backup your data and reinstall Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I disagree. Everything else works and it's a GUI dependency.